# Rxjava observable incompatible types

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

Im trying to return the number of times a word occurs in a text document using rxjava, i keep getting an error saying

```
incompatible types: Single Long cannot be converted to Observable String
```

the function that I'm using is :

```
static public Observable<String> WordCount(Observable<String> lineEmitter, String startTerm){
    return lineEmitter.flatMap(str -> Observable.fromArray(str.split("\\s")))
            .filter(str -> str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").contains(startTerm))
            .count();
}
```

I think it is to do with the count at the end making it a single long but I dont know how to convert it to a string

Comment: rxjava 2.0, the dependency is 2.2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear, you are using `.count()` which return `Single<Long>` and not `Observable<String>` instead you have to use :

```
static public Single<Long> wordCount(Observable<String> lineEmitter, String startTerm){
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or if you want to get the count as Long you can use `.blockingGet()`

```
static public Long WordCount(Observable<String> lineEmitter, String startTerm){
    return lineEmitter.flatMap(str -> Observable.fromArray(str.split("\\s")))
            .filter(str -> str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").contains(startTerm))
            .count()
            .blockingGet();
}
```

---

Advice: Please don't use UpperCase in first letter of method